# Why does `/=` raise an error but not `x = x / y` with a read-only numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I've always thought `x /= y` is equal to `x = x / y`. But now I'm facing a situation that I'll have an error when I use `/=` but not when using `x = x / y`. so definitely they shouldn't be the same in python.

The code is this. (is a simple deep learning code in Tensorflow, **read code comments for some details**).

```
import tensorflow as tf
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()

# x_train is a (60000, 28, 28) numpy matrix

x_train /= 1 # this will raise error "ValueError: output array is read-only"
x_train = x_train / 1 # but this will work fine
```

> ```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-44-fceb080f135a> in <module>()
>       1 
> ----> 2 x_train /= 1
>
> ValueError: output array is read-only
> ```

I want to ask the difference between them. Why I'm getting this error from `/=`?

Comment: What error? Stack trace please. Generally the error message is there to speak for itself.

Comment: `/=` is trying to do an _in-place_ change, which only works with mutable values. `x_train = x_train / 1` is putting a reference to a _different_ immutable value in the variable. So as Mad Physicist says -- the error message itself does a pretty good job of telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Why is there a numpy tag? Aren't you using tf?

Comment: @MadPhysicist tf uses NumPy and the x_train is a NumPy array. it is written in the code's comment.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's in the comment of the code "ValueError: output array is read-only"

Comment: This is _related_ to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849870/why-return-anything-but-self-from-iadd (though that handles `+=` rather than `/=`, answers go into the closely related reasoning to why you see the behavior you do).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy very interesting! thanks for that.

Comment: Fun fact: calling `x/=1` on the result of `x=x/1` will likely work just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As given in [Immutable numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541324/immutable-numpy-array), numpy arrays can be explicitly marked *read-only*.

When you run `somearray /= value`, you're asking that array to be modified, in a way that (for typical mutable objects, like *most* numpy arrays) changes not just the individual reference, but the object itself; this means *all* copies of `somearray` (including ones internal to the tensorflow library that provided it) are subject to the change.

By contrast, when you run `somearray = somearray / value`, you're creating a *new* object, not modifying the old one, so there's no conflict with `somearray` being marked read-only.

The implementation of `__itruediv__` in use *could* return a completely new object instead of modifying a read-only array, thus making `/=` on read-only arrays work the same way `+=` works for integers; however, this would mean having the operation allocate memory -- potentially expensive; for numpy, it makes sense to not do expensive things unless the author knows they're being done, so people don't write unnecessarily slow code by mistake. (Having the read-only flag significantly change performance and memory usage characteristics of an object would be a fair bit of extra state that a developer needs to keep in their head to write correct code!)

Answer (score 6):

It has to do with python operator semantics and the principle of least surprise.

- The expression `x = x + 1` is approximately equivalent to `x = type(x).__add__(x, 1)`
- The expression `x += 1` is approximately equivalent to `x = type(x).__iadd__(x, 1)`

By convention, `__add__` never mutates the object it is invoked on. `__iadd__` sometimes does and sometimes doesn't. There are examples of both among Python's built-ins:

- `int` and `str` are immutable, so always return a new object. The re-assignment step is very important in this case, since otherwise the name wouldn't get bound to the new value.
- `list` adds in-place. The reassignment is effectively a no-op in this case (but it still happens).

Numpy arrays are usually mutable. Operations like `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, etc. are truly in-place. In fact, they are supported by the same ufuncs that support the regular operations (`add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, `true_divide`), using the `out` parameter.

The developers had a choice to make for read-only arrays: either change the semantics of `__iadd__`, or raise an error. The principle of least surprise dictated the latter: a function should not change its fundamental behavior under certain circumstances without telling you. It's safe to assume that you used `__iadd__` rather than `__add__` because you wanted an in-place operation. The function notifies you when it can't do that, because the alternative is to do something you specifically didn't ask for.